# calculating a point on circumference

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

See the diagram
[image]

Known values are

```
A: (-87.91, 41.98)
B: (-104.67, 39.85)
C: (-96.29, 40.92)
L: 14.63  // L is OC
```

Known angles

```
ADB: 60 deg
BAD: 60 deg
ADF: 10 deg
```

How to calculate Point F? that is 10 deg from point A.

Comment: L is OC or OE ?

Comment: Homework assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Given that two of the angles in $\triangle ABO$ have measure $60°$, $\triangle ABO$ is equilateral.  It appears that $C$ is the midpoint of $\overline{AB}$, so $L$ is the length of an altitude of $\triangle ABO$ and the lengths of the sides of the triangle are $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}L\approx16.89$.  Now, $O$ is $16.89$ from both $A$ and $B$, which gives a system of equations that can be solved for the coordinates of $O$: $(-94.4456,26.4022)$ (as shown in your picture, so I'll use this one) or $(-98.1344,55.4278)$ (which would be above $\overline{AB}$).

Assuming that the arc shown is intended to be circular and centered at $O$, $F$ is the image of $A$ under a $10°$ rotation about $O$, which we can carry out by applying to $A$:

1. a translation that takes $O$ to $(0,0)$, $(x,y)\to(x+98.1344,y-55.4278)$,
2. a rotation of $10°$ about the origin, $(x,y)\to(x\cos10°-y\sin10°,y\cos10°+x\sin10°)$, and
3. a translation that takes $(0,0)$ to $O$, $(x,y)\to(x-98.1344,y+55.4278)$.

Carrying out these transformations on $A$ gives $$F\approx(-90.7144, 42.8782).$$

Answer (score 0):

if L is OE then u have the radius,

OA= L

AF = $\frac{\theta }{2\pi }2\pi r$ where r=L

u know A,O

so solve the 2 equations to get coordinates of F

Comment: sorry! L is OC. but I can calculate R using R = tan(30) x L

Comment: can you please explain how to calculate F? I need Fx and Fy!

Answer (score 0):

C is exactly the center of AB, so COA = 30 deg. 
AOF is 10 deg (given), so EOF is 20 deg.

Calculate R using tan(30)•L. Calculate d(F,EO) using R•sin(20).

The entire shape is turned, so turn everything so that OE and the y-axis are parallel.